# How to get coordinates of a point in a coordinate system based on angle and distance

Tags: java, math, trigonometry

How to get coordinates of a point in a coordinate system when all I have is the origin coordinates (x, y) and the angle from the origin to the point and the distance from the origin to the point?

Comment: Sounds like more of a math (algebra specifically) question, than a computing question.  Do you know the formulae needed to calculate the new point?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolarCoordinates.html or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system

Comment: Depends on the type of the coordinate system, but most of the time using the simple trigonometric functions called sin(), cos().

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You use [`Math.cos`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#cos%28double%29), [`Math.sin`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#sin%28double%29) like this:

```
pointX = x + distance * Math.cos(angle)
pointY = y + distance * Math.sin(angle)
```

[image]

### Note about radians / degrees

`Math.cos` and `Math.sin` assumes the argument is given in **radians** (0…2π). If you have the angle in degrees (0…360), you would use `Math.cos(`[`Math.toRadians(angle)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#toRadians%28double%29)`)` for instance.

Comment: +1: Since it actually uses Java-functions, which my answer did not :)

Comment: How could this be modified for a 3D system?

Answer (score 3):

If d is the distance and A is the angle, than the coordnates of the point will be

**(x+d*Cos(A), y+ d*Sin(A))**

Comment: This is wrong since it does not take into account that the point is offset some other arbitrary point (x,y).

Comment: @kigurai; Thanks for pointing it. Edited the code. It was in my mind while typing I dont know how I missed it... Anyways thanks once again...

Answer (score 3):

If `r` is the distance from origin and `a` is the angle (in radians) between x-axis and the point you can easily calculate the coordinates with a conversion from polar coordinates:

```
x = r*cos(a)
y = r*sin(a)
```

(this assumes that origin is placed at `(0,0)`, otherwise you should add the displacement to the final result).

The inverse result is made by computing the modulo of the vector (since a distance + angle make a vector) and the arctangent, which can be calculated by using the `atan2` funcion.

```
r = sqrt(x*2+y*2)
a = atan2(y,x)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
px = x + r * cos(phi)
py = y + r * sin(phi)
```

where `[px py]` is the point you are searching for, `[x y]` is the "origin", `r` is the distance and `phi` is the angle to the target from the origin.

EDIT: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system This link which was helpfully posted by Bart Kiers could yield some background information.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**

```
// math equations    
pointX = distance * cos(angle) + x  
pointY = distance * sin(angle) + y

// java code [angle in radian]
double pointX = distance * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle)) + x;  
double pointY = distance * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle)) + y;
```

**Detailed answer**

As per below diagram

```
// finding pointX let's start by 
cos(angle) = (pointX - x) / distance
distance * cos(angle) =  (pointX - x)
(pointX - x) = distance * cos(angle)
pointX = distance * cos(angle) + x

// finding pointY let's start by 
sin(angle) = (pointY - y) / distance
distance * sin(angle) =  (pointY - y)
(pointY - y) = distance * sin(angle)
pointY = distance * sin(angle) + y
```

[image]