# Calculate coordinates of a point based on sine/cosine

Tags: r, geometry, trigonometry

let me begin by saying that I've read through [Calculate point A from given point E and angle and afterwards calculate Point A from E and angle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1554604/calculate-point-a-from-given-point-e-and-angle-and-afterwards-calculate-point-a?noredirect=1&lq=1) , [Calculate point, given x, y, angle, and distance](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143932/calculate-point-given-x-y-angle-and-distance?noredirect=1&lq=1) , [a problem involving trigonometry functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1421656/a-problem-involving-trigonometry-functions), and especially [How to get coordinates of a point in a coordinate system based on angle and distance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9871727/how-to-get-coordinates-of-a-point-in-a-coordinate-system-based-on-angle-and-dist) and none of them managed to lift the veil of confusion, surrounding me.

*What I am doing:* I want to create a sort of Instantaneous Field of View (FOV) for a bunch of sequences of points; the FOVs would represent what is visible from each point, depending of course, on the direction at which we are looking at ( 0 - North; 90 - East; 180 - South; 270 - West; 360 - North). The FOV is essentially a triangle, where the central (C) vertex is the point itself, vertex A and vertex B, whose coordinates I am looking for, being the ones connected to the base of the triangle.

*The code snippet:*  I am essentially approaching this via leveraging two right triangles, that together constitute the FOV, like so:

[image]

## --------- A VERTEX -------------

```
for (p in 1:nrow(pnp.90.deg@data)){   #pnp is the spatial points dataframe, containing attribute information such as lon/lat(coordinates) and ca(camera angle - showing the direction of sight/movement in degrees)
   a_alfa1 <- pnp.90.deg@data$ca - (pnp.90.deg@data$ca - 60)
   a_alfa1rad <- a_alfa1 * (pi/180)
   a_x1 <- pnp.90.deg@data$lon + 0.00035 * cos(a_alfa1rad)
   a_y1 <- pnp.90.deg@data$lat + 0.00035 * sin(a_alfa1rad) 
   avert1 <- cbind(a_x1, a_y1)
   colnames(avert1) <- c("lon", "lat") 
   avert.90<-SpatialPoints(avert1, proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84      +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"), bbox=NULL) 
 }
```

## --------- B VERTEX -------------

```
for (p in 1:nrow(pnp.90.deg@data)){
  b_alfa1 <- pnp.90.deg@data$ca - (pnp.90.deg@data$ca + 60)
  b_alfa1rad <- b_alfa1 * (pi/180)
  b_x1 <- pnp.90.deg@data$lon + 0.00035 * cos(b_alfa1rad)
  b_y1 <- pnp.90.deg@data$lat + 0.00035 * sin(b_alfa1rad)
  bvert1 <- cbind(b_x1, b_y1)
  colnames(bvert1) <- c("lon", "lat") 
  bvert.90<-SpatialPoints(bvert1, proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"), bbox=NULL) 
}
```

*The result:* the code produces the triangle as one would expect, yet it does so only when the angle (ca) is between 0-90 degrees:

[image]

**The Problem**

> This formula doesn't seem to work for other camera angles. To my mind (and according to the provided links to topics) the formula should be universally applicable for any angle measure. Can someone provide some input on whether I am a) using the right formula and b) using it in the correct way.

UPDATE: link to the spatial points data frame in shapefile format:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ax5OG8c8Cl-Hz3N16ye9OoG4z7l8HSAQ/view?usp=sharing

UPDATE 2: The process of getting from the pnpover (the shared spdf) to pnp.90.deg is just a spatial subset:

```
pnp.90.deg <- subset(pnpover, pnpover@data$ca <= 90)
```

I decided to bucket looking angles in ranges of 0-90; 91-180; 181-270; 271-360 in order to test what was going wrong.

Thank you kindly!

Comment: Posting problem code without data is a cause for question closure.

Comment: Apologies for that, I updated the post to include the spdf I am using.

Comment: You need to show the R code that takes you from 0_DemoGrassland_MetaData to pnp.90.deg@data

Comment: @42- the operations are a few and consist of harvesting said points (that actually represent images) and performing some buffer and intersect to only keep points(images) within a certain area. The next step is the FOV generation. and pnp.90.deg is just a spatial subset of the file I shared that holds only the 0-90 degree images.

Comment: What exactly does *"doesn't seem to work"* mean? As far as I see, `alfa1` is always +- 60 and does not depend on `pnp.90.deg@data$ca`. Is this correct?

Comment: @NicoSchertler yes, indeed I would like all the FOVs to be the same shape and size, which requires them to have the same angles. By "doesn't work" I mean something like this happening: https://imgur.com/a/NCSeqfm . For this result I ran the same code but on a sequence of points (images) that have a looking angle (ca) between 270-360.

Comment: Unless I've grossly misunderstood R syntax, `pnp.90.deg@data$ca - (pnp.90.deg@data$ca + 60)` should not depend on the angle `ca` at all...

Comment: @meowgoesthedog , yes the angle would always be the same, that is quite central to my idea - have the same triangle build from each point.

Comment: But your first problem statement is that the code does not work for any values of `ca` outside 0-90 degrees.

Comment: Correct, might you elaborate on where you are going with this?

Comment: So these two statements are contradictory...? Can you clarify what the actual problem is? Does it occur when the "60" is changed to > 90? In such a case, the triangle will become inverted, so what you need is a circular sector, or a "fan".

Comment: What is wrong with the picture you posted? What @meowgoesthedog and I mean is that you should replace your alfa calculation with `pnp.90.deg@data$ca + 60` and `pnp.90.deg@data$ca - 60`. Otherwise, all triangles will look in the same direction.

Comment: Why? I am grounding the angle to a local angle within the respective triangle, while still wanting to keep the overall direction the base (long side) would be facing. Maybe a bit of a prehistory - initially i tried with `a_alfa1 <- pnp@data$ca +/- 60` and that produced equally unsatisfactory results when ran on larger angles. That is why I decided to ground it in the local one. The problem is that, to my mind using the formula for arriving at rectangular coordinates (x,y) using the polar coordinates (r, angle) should work universally. Just to clarify "increased angle" relates to ca

Comment: As I pointed out, a triangle approach is not **supposed** to work with reflex angles, as it will invert. This doesn't mean `pnp@data$ca +/- 60` is wrong in itself - you applied the wrong fix because you didn't know what the source of the problem was.

Comment: Ok, that was informative. I was myself puzzled as to how to get this triangle stuff to work when angles are so big that the total sum of all three becomes larger than 180. Hence my (not too intelligent) solution. I wonder then, would you have a suggestion? As of now I am bucketing angles in the groups of the four sectors and working a custom angle-radius solution, but this is not too efficient...

Comment: The angle for sin/cos usage is the angle of the tangent at central vertex (lon,lat) **added** with +-60/2, being '60' the inner angle to the FOV.

Comment: @Ripi2 , I though that is what I am doing:
- cos/sin(camera angle -/+ 60) * r(distance) + x/y, no?

Comment: What is `camera angle`? If it's the direction on view in general axis, that's right. If it's an inner angle, that's wrong.

Comment: @Ripi2 , camera angle is the direction, in which the point (image) is looking at: 0 - North; 90 - East; 180 - South; 270 - West; 360 - North . So a point with a `ca` of 45 is looking north-east, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this picture:

[image]

with:

- `ca` is the direction where the camera points to. It is angle that starts at North and goes clockwise, so 0=North, 90=East, etc.
- `fa` is the inner angle for the field of view (FOV).
- `C` is the camera position.
- `A` and `B` are the coordinates to calculate. Their distance to `C` is `d`.

You may already know the conversion from polar to Cartesian coordinates:
`x = cx + d * cos(alpha)` and `y = cy + d * sin(alpha)`

But we have said that `ca` goes **clockwise**. It means that we must change `sin/cos` usage.

The needed formulas are:

```
x = cx + d * sin(alpha)
y = cy + d * cos(alpha)
```

So, for A, B coordinates:

```
ax = cx + d * sin(ca - fa/2)
ay = cy + d * cos(ca - fa/2)
bx = cx + d * sin(ca + fa/2)
by = cy + d * cos(ca + fa/2)
```

These are valid formulas for the whole of `{0, 360}` range. Or `{0, 2PI}` as you prefer.

If the origin was different from North (say 0=East) then we would need some sign corrections.

Likely the compiler is able to use any angle, even out of `{0, 2PI}` range. If not, you must first clamp the angle into the range. I don't *speak* `r`, so I write it in general form:

```
float parts = angle / 360
float rest = parts - int(parts)
float cAngle = rest * 360
better cAngleRadians = rest * 2 *pi
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort! I really appreciated it! It doesn't seem to work for me though: On the picture: I have this point (C), the camera angle (ca) is 85 and after executing your suggestion I get the following result: https://imgur.com/a/ixhUMKy , whereas the triangle should point its base at the direction of the arrow. Let me ask you this: is `fa` supposed to be a fixed value, vis-a-vis, if I want the measure of that angle to be 60, then it's sixty for every point. OR, `fa = ca -/+ 60` (for example) ? Again - thank you very much for your time!

Comment: @Momchill In your image it seems you have a 90-degree error for camera angle `ca`. Are you sure your `ca` follows the meanings of my picture?

Comment: @Momchill I'm using my own picture meanings. So `fa` is always the same, unless you want a different field of view amplitude for each center `C`.

Comment: I am quite sure. And, yes, I also want `ca` to be constant.  So, your suggestion works fine for your images, all of which have different `ca` and you manage to produce triangular FOVs with the up-stated formula? Can you share this point shapefile so that I may try it myself?

Comment: One more thing - why do you do `fa / 2` ?

Comment: @Momchill Sorry. I don't use any *shapefile*. And I don't know how to open the files you linked to in your post.

Comment: @Momchill `fa` is the angle A-C-B. `fa/2` is the angle A-C-direction or B-C-direction. I suppose the FOV is centered in this 'direction' definde by angle `ca`

Comment: I stand corrected, sir, your solution produces the desired results, yet I was foolish in not afore-hand converting my coordinate pairs from WGS84 to the relevant UTM zone, or whatever other projected CRS. This was causing the triangles to be skewed in whichever direction. I thank you!